# Robocopy Long File Name

Tags: windows, windows-10, robocopy, windows-server-2016, windows-backup

Windows 10 run in our users' company PCs, long path name errors appears to them while trying to transfer files from the PCs to the windows server 2016

Users do not want to Flatten the folder structure, instead, they keep increasing the deepness, and obviously the results are errors while transferring or deleting data.

I tried to troubleshooter this issue but no way, personally I use robocopy , please help ?

Comment: Tell your users to shorten the names. That is the answer. Too bad if they don’t want to. That’s the rules.

Comment: Our work required to make subfolders and to go on with a specific structure with every user, so shorten the names was not suitable to us, but the problem solved with Gs richcopy 360, the SW that recommended by user AdamCola207

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to see if your supporting software like backups (and their ability to restore) can support. 200 character long paths are very long.

Then IT should never edit paths or folder names unless you know what users are doing or have done. Users may have path names in formulae in excel for example that links data from excel to excel files. By changing paths, you maybe causing cell errors etc.

I suggest to give training to users to keep below the 150 or 180 character limit would be recommended (give buffer).

For Me, I use Gs Richcopy 360 , it is an important solution inside my company to handle long file names with every user .

Comment: Thanks, AdamCola207, your recommendation(gs richcopy 360) was helpful to us , we did not face any  long pathnames problems after using it.